# Google Cloud Build of NodeJS to App engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, build

I am trying to do a trigger based build of a NodeJS app using Google's Cloud build.

I have my code in Bitbucket and the repository is mirrored into Google's Source Repository. The repo has both a client and server directory. I have the client part of the repo firing up a build of a react app and deploying to a Firebase hosted website.

The server app though is causing me all kinds of trouble in locating the `app.yaml` file. If I do the build locally from the server directory via `gcloud app deploy` my deploy is fine.

If I push the application to my repo and try to use Google Cloud build I have issues in locating the `app.yaml` file

My `cloudbuild.yaml` file

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['app', 'deploy', 'app.yaml']
    dir: 'server'
```

and my `app.yaml`

```
env: flex


    manual_scaling:
      instances: 1
    resources:
      cpu: 1
      memory_gb: 0.5
      disk_size_gb: 10
```

I then receive an error saying it cannot find the `app.yaml` file

`Step #1: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [/workspace/server/app.yaml] does not exist.`

I have resorted to using docker to build an image and deploy that way, but cannot figure out why this is not working. I assume I am missing something obvious like the app.yaml does not exist, but it is there in the repo.

Comment: Are you missing the root directory name? Perhaps the dir variable should be 'root_dir_name/server', which would resolve to /workspace/root_dir_name/server/app.yaml'

Comment: Can you confirm if you still have the issue?

Comment: I am still having the issue. @ChristopherP I am not 100% about your comment about the _root_dir_name_... I am pushing from Bitbucket to Google's source code repository and then I build from there. My 
understanding is workspace is the root directory in those instances.

I have another deploy that builds a react app and the workspace piece seems to be okay. 

I can provide a build id if that helps troubleshoot

Comment: @JohnPtacek 
Cloud Build creates the /workspace directory by default. With dir: 'server' it will resolve as  '/workspace/server/app.yaml'. What ChristopherP means is to make sure you don't have a parent directory before 'server', if so you would have to change the cloudbuild.yaml field to dir: 'your_app_root_dir/server'. That would resolve to ' /workspace/your_app_root_dir/server/app.yaml'. Let me know if that's the case.

Comment: @JohnPtacek The app.yaml format posted in your question shows a weird indentation. I'm not sure if your file is actually like that or if it misconfigured in the Stackoverflow editor. I recommend you to take a look at the indentation following this [model](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/hello-world/flexible/app.yaml).

Comment: @dhauptman I will validate it, but I use that `app.yaml` to do a build from the command line and it works.

Comment: @john-ptacek Did you sort this out?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Switch to GAE standard since it was mostly node